Eliminate Antartica from mapPie plot (rworldmap)
Unable to eliminate Antartica from mapPies plot, rworldmap. I would like to eliminate Antartica from the map, but do not know how. I have tried setting ylim = c(-60, 90) or ylim = c(-50, 90) and removing the mapRegion argument but it only moves the map instead of removing Antartica. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks a lot! I have the following code:
    mapPies(dF = map_data,
    nameX = "LON",
    nameY = "LAT",
    nameZs = nameZs,
    mapRegion = "world",
    zColours = rainbow(length(nameZs)),  # Use a color palette
    symbolSize = 1,
    maxZVal = NA,
    borderCol = "black",
    oceanCol = NA,
    landCol = NA,
    lwd = 0.5,
    addCatLegend = FALSE)

